# joining 3 table and return

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 3 table which are Timetable, Schedule and Consultation slot
and i wish to combine them so that all the data are able to retrieve easily

Timetable are having

```
1. TimetableID
2. Lecture ID
3. ClassVenue
4. ClassStartTime
5. ClassEndTime
```

Schedule

```
1. ScheduleID
2. LectureID
3. ScheduleVenue
4. ScheduleStartTime
5. ScheduleEndTime
```

Consultation Slot

```
1. ConsultationID
2. LectureID
3. StudentID
4. ScheduleID
5. remark
```

Here is my code in metadata

```
Partial Public Class CombinationOfTSC
    <Key()> _
    Public Property LectureID() As String
        Get
            Return m_LectureID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_LectureID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_LectureID As String

    Public Property StudentID() As String
        Get
            Return m_StudentID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_StudentID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StudentID As String

    Public Property ttID() As String
        Get
            Return m_ttID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ttID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ttID As String

    Public Property ttClassVenue() As String
        Get
            Return m_ttClassVenue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ttClassVenue = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ttClassVenue As String

    Public Property ttClassStartTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_ttClassStartTime
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_ttClassStartTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ttClassStartTime As DateTime

    Public Property ttClassEndTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_ttClassEndTime
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_ttClassEndTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ttClassEndTime As DateTime

    Public Property scID() As String
        Get
            Return m_scID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_scID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_scID As String

    Public Property scVenue() As String
        Get
            Return m_scVenue
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_scVenue = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_scVenue As String

    Public Property scStartTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_scStartTime
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_scStartTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_scStartTime As DateTime

    Public Property scEndTime() As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_scEndTime
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_scEndTime = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_scEndTime As DateTime

    Public Property cID() As String
        Get
            Return m_cID
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_cID = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_cID As String

    Public Property cRemark() As String
        Get
            Return m_cRemark
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_cRemark = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_cRemark As String
End Class
```

In my domain class the code will be

```
Public Function GetCoTSC(lectureID As String) As IQueryable(Of CombinationOfTSC)
        Dim CSC As IQueryable(Of CombinationOfTSC) = From c In ObjectContext.ConsultationSlots Join s In ObjectContext.Schedules On c.ScheduleID Equals s.ScheduleID Join t In ObjectContext.TimeTables On t.LectureID Equals s.LectureID Where c.LectureID = s.LectureID = t.LectureID Select New CombinationOfTSC() With { _
                      .cID = c.ConsultationID, _
            .cRemark = c.Remark, _
            .StudentID = c.StudentID, _
             .LectureID = s.LectureID, _
            .scStartTime = s.ScheduleStartTime, _
            .scEndTime = s.ScheduleEndTime, _
            .scID = s.ScheduleID, _
            .scVenue = s.ScheduleVenue, _
              .ttID = t.TimeTableID, _
              .ttClassVenue = t.ClassVenue, _
              .ttClassStartTime = t.ClassStartTime, _
            .ttClassEndTime = t.ClassEndTime}
        Return CSC
    End Function
```

I'm having error at `c.LectureID = s.LectureID = t.LectureID`
I wish to get the combination of 3 tables through the lectureID since there are lecture ID on 3 tables. 
Anyone helps pls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have x=y=z. Have you tried seperating these out into pairs?

Comment: Lol. i agree. 
But any idea how to do so ?
how u mean by separate into pairs ? any examples ?

Comment: Don't know if you can seperate by ANDs. c.LectureID = s.LectureID AND c.LectureID = t.LectureID AND s.LectureID = t.LectureID.

Comment: nw i testing with s.lectureID = t.lectureID

Comment: Everything seem fine now. The only problem is i can't receive any item inside it nw. any idea ?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the AND solution? So I've got a base to look at the new issue.

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the whole where clause as the joins seem to be taking care of that.

Comment: no error pop out once added with AND solution but the problem is no data are combined while nothing is disappear on my web.

Comment: Have you tried removing the where clause entirely and seeing if the joins are doing that correctly?

Comment: I think the joins having some problem since none of things are shown ><

Answer (score 0):

try `Where c.LectureID = s.LectureID and s.LectureID = t.LectureID` in stead of `Where c.LectureID = s.LectureID = t.LectureID`

Comment: Tried. I think i having the problem of joining since i remove the t object. There still show nothing ><